# JetBrains IDE: Disabling CoffeeScript -> .js file generation on save

Tags: coffeescript, pycharm

I am using PyCharm to edit CoffeeScript files. Every time I save the file, PyCharm invokes a transpiler and generates .js file in the same folder as .coffee file.

This behavior is undesirable and I don't want my IDE to generate .js files.

I have not found a way to disable this behavior, even after going through File Watcher / Inspection settings and disabling inspections for CoffeeScript, as [instructed in JetBrains IDE documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-file-watchers.html#d197505e913).

How I can disable PyCharm (or other JetBrains IDEs) to automatically generate .js files from .coffee files?

Answer (score 0):

Please disable file watcher per instructions in Help: go to Settings/Tools/File Watchers, select `CoffeeScript` file watcher there, clear the check box next to it

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. JS files are still being generated.

Comment: very strange indeed. Can you attach a screenshot of Settings/Tools/File Watchers page?

Comment: Will do. I'll try to record an animation.